# Why does os.IsNotExist not return the current response when looking at a windows share? GoLang

Tags: go

When I run this code.

```
fileInfo, err := os.Stat("\\\\server\\sharedFolder\\file.txt") //The file is located on a windows share.
if err != nil {
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Fatal("->File does not exist. ",) 
    }
} else {
    fmt.Println("File does exist.")
}
```

The thing is it always says the file does not exist but I get the file size and other information from fileInfo. The file does exist and i can open it. I do open it and read information from it later on in my code but the os.IsNotExist always returns false information saying it does not exist when it does. Why is this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try with go1.5? that seems more like a bug.

Comment: I did but it didn't change the way it was acting.